# Recreate resulting CSV as own file in Azure blob

Tags: azure, scala, hadoop

When writing out my dataframe, it drop the result into a folder called "file.csv" with a "part-000..." file.  I need to take this resulting file and write it out/copy it as its own csv file with a name.  I am using the [logic here](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-write-dataframe-single-csv-file/), but it appears this won't suffice for Azure blob as it's not recognizing a WASB path.

Code to create the dataframe:

```
val dfOutput = spark.sql("""SELECT * FROM Query""")
dfOutput.coalesce(1).write.option("header","true").mode("overwrite").format("csv").save(OutputFile)
```

Creates and outputs the dataframe as a CSV file within a folder as a "part-000..." file.  The output path in this case is `wasb:/mycontainer@myexamplestorage.blob.core.windows.net/file.csv` (example).

The next part should grab the "part-000..." file and create it under its own file by copying it with the `FileUtil` then remove the "file.csv" path.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, FileUtil, Path}
import java.io.{File}

val hadoopConfig = new Configuration()
val hdfs = FileSystem.get(hadoopConfig)
val srcPath = new Path(OutputFile)
val destPath = new Path("wasb://mycontainer@myexamplestorage.blob.core.windows.net/resultfile.csv")
val srcFile = FileUtil.listFiles(new File(OutputFile))
           .filterNot(f=>f.getPath.endsWith(".csv"))(0)

FileUtil.copy(srcFile,hdfs,destPath,true,hadoopConfig)
hdfs.delete(srcPath,true)
```

This next part fails on the `listFiles` with the error "
IOException: Invalid directory or I/O error occurred for dir: wasb://mycontainer@myexamplestorage.blob.core.windows.net/file.csv" and from what I can tell this is caused because it's not able to list files from Azure blob storage.

I need to be able to get the CSV file from Azure blob, then copy it as its own file to Azure blob without the folder and "part-000..." file.  I played around with setting the file configuration, but this entire approach appears to be incompatible with Azure blob storage or there is a configuration missing somewhere that allows these to query blob storage.

Comment: I think you need to add Azure and hadoop tags to the question

Comment: But why do you need this? Spark does not like having single files and any tool you're using with Hadoop can read the whole directory instead of needing a single file (or `.csv` file extension). If you want to really query "tabular data", or process that data (not as a plaintext file) later, you should load into a real database, not blob storage. You also don't need Hadoop SDK to manipulate files in WASB